# Email after form submit change it to multi-part type in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, newline, multipart

in my `Codeigniter` project, there are many mails are sending from many modules. I have one common config with `newline` as `\n`. **But only in one form it showing the `MIME Type error`**. But I resolved it with another `config` with `newline` as `\r\n`.

**The page have a multipart form. And the mail is working after the submitting of the form.**

But my mail doesn't contain any attachments. It is just an `html` type mail.

My question is **Can I send the mail with out the `MIME type error` by using the same config file with `newline` as `\n` only?**

My mail is working with additional config. But I want to know whether it is possible and the reason for the behavior.

Any help could be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using double quotes to wrap that `"\n"`?

Comment: @Tpojka, Yeah. Double quotes. I managed it by using "$this->email->set_newline("\r\n")". So that I need not create another configuration.